# How to fix or what causes The remote server returned an unexpected response error

Tags: asp.net-core, proxy, asp.net-core-3.1

I created an API and added swagger documentation in NET CORE 3.1 however when I deploy the web api to IIS on a remote server and try to make a call to one of the methods I receive the following error:

**The remote server returned an unexpected response: (502) Proxy Error ( Forefront TMG denied the specified Uniform Resource Locator (URL).  ).**

Can somebody explain what causes that error? Everything works perfectly when I run the project locally.

```
[2020-08-26 12:12:33] [Server] [ERROR] [(null)] [? ?] [Application.Core.Helpers.Helper:?] - System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The remote server returned an unexpected response: (502) Proxy Error ( Forefront TMG denied the specified Uniform Resource Locator (URL).  ).
```

at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

Comment: Forefront TMG is your proxy in between your client and the server and `502` basically indicates that `The server, while acting as a gateway or proxy, received an invalid response from the upstream server it accessed in attempting to fulfill the request.`  It could possibly be because of many reasons.

Comment: Could be because there is something you are missing in the configuration at your proxy level. It will not be possible to speculate with very little context. Can you provide more context aka logs for your scenario? Also, maybe this answer might help you. https://serverfault.com/questions/249194/forefront-tmg-proxy-blocking-internal-http-requests-for-fqdn

Comment: @SaiGummaluri I updated the question to include what is received in the logs.